# Query parameter using JS framework?

Tags: javascript

I seem to not be able to find implementation from the common Ajax libraries (JQuery, mootools, prototypejs...) that would allow the operation of parsing the *window.location.href* for request parameter. I would expect something like:

```
$P{"param1"} == "param1_value"
```

Am I missing something?

p.s. The web does contains [implementation examples](http://www.netlobo.com/url_query_string_javascript.html) for such operations

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's really easy in vanilla javascript

```
var Query = (function(){
    var query = {}, pair, search = location.search.substring(1).split("&"), i = search.length;
    while (i--) {
        pair = search[i].split("=");
        query[pair[0]] = decodeURIComponent(pair[1]);
    }
    return query;
}());


alert(Query["foo"]);
```

Comment: cool! And it works for all the cases I can think of :)

Could you please explain the code? I'm not a javascript programmers and there are lots of things I'm not clear about, for example what does location.search reference? What does decodeURIComponent() do? Comments for logic would be very helpful here...